# How to add multiple dynamic fields to a form using jquery & bootstrap 3.1

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have multiple groups of dynamic fields I need to add to a form, I used an example to get the main bit working, but I need to setup the javascript to 'target' specific set of

[Here is a bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/0CstxlrED8)

You can see that when the add button is clicked it adds[clones] a new field in the file-controls div. I need to somehow detect the class of the parent [well, 4th predecessor]  div when the add button gets clicked.

How is this done?

HTML:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" class="form" role="form" action="[[~[[*id]]]]" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="[[+id]]">


    <div class="row">

      <div class="form-group col-sm-6 [[!+fi.error.expires:notempty=` has-error`]]">
        <label for="expires">Expires</label>
        <select name="expires" class="form-control">
          <option value="24">24 hours</option>
          <option value="48">48 hours</option>
          <option value="72">72 hours</option>
          <option value="96">96 hours</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-sm-6 [[!+fi.error.origin:notempty=` has-error`]]">
          <label for="origin">Origin</label>
          <input name="origin" type="text" id="origin" value="" class="form-control">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-12"><label>Tag numbers: </label></div>

      <div class="tag-controls"> 

        <div class="entry col-sm-4">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-12"><label>Photos: </label></div>

      <div class="image-controls"> 

        <div class="entry col-sm-4">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>   

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-12"><label>Files: </label></div>

      <div class="file-controls"> 

        <div class="entry col-sm-4">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" class="btn button-sm btn-primary">Add Special Offering</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Javascript:

```
// dynamic add form fields
$(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e){

        console.log('button clicked');
        e.preventDefault();

        var controlForm = $('.file-controls'),
        currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
        newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

        console.log(controlForm);
        console.log(currentEntry);
        console.log(newEntry);

        newEntry.find('input').val('');
        controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
        .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
        .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-info')
        .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
        }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
        {

        $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;

    });

});
```

Comment: The 4th Predecessor is .image-controls?  change your `$(this).parents('.entry:first');` to `$(this).parents('.image-controls');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give your container DIV ("image-controls" , "tag-controls" ...) another class to identify them as groupcontainer ... Like "**myformgroup**"

And approach it with $(this).closest(identifier) ...

For example:

```
<div class="tag-controls myformgroup"> 
            <div class="entry col-sm-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">add</span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And in your JS:

```
            var container = $(this).closest(".myformgroup");
            var classNames = $(container).attr("class");
            var className = classNames.replace("myformgroup", "");
            alert(className.trim());
```

But now you can only use your controls-name and the "identifier" as class for the control wrapper.

I would recommend the use of "data-target" for your button:

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"><label>Tag numbers: </label></div>

        <div class="tag-controls"> 
            <div class="entry col-sm-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" data-target="tag-controls" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">add</span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
alert($(this).data()["target"]);
```

Comment: Thanks, the data target looks the be the most elegant and reusable of the solutions. All I had to do was change the jquery:  var controlForm = $("." + $(this).data()["target"]),

Answer (score 1):

The below jquery in your button click event would find the 4 predecessor:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('class');
```

It might be a better idea to tag these parents with a more unique class then get the collection of `$(this).parents(...)` using this class name as a selector in the jquery.  Below is a snippet of the html change you would need and the jquery

```
    //jquery

    console.log($(this).parents('.addBtnCntr').attr('class'));

    <!--html-->    
    <div class="tag-controls addBtnCntr">     
        <div class="entry col-sm-4">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier way would be:

```
$(".formClass").append("<input id=3 />");
```